# How to parse value from a url in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, nsurl

I have a url :

```
DBSession url : db-qf8erkjgfnhno://1/connect?oauth_token_secret=7ek3fhnfnhla&state=58444830-7764-4DBE-A4F1-84B8604sv2C5&oauth_token=c93dvvaa5b47&uid=2841089
```

I want to take the value of `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_token`. I tried with `[url query]` method and get `oauth_token_secret=7ek3fhnfnhla&state=58444830-7764-4DBE-A4F1-84B8604sv2C5&oauth_token=c93dvvaa5b47&uid=2841089`, but i can not find the method to get the value of `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_token`.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse query parameters into NSMutableDictionary, and after that retrieve values from there.

```
NSString *query = [url query];  
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *param in [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
  NSArray *elts = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
  if([elts count] < 2) continue;
  [params setObject:[elts objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[elts objectAtIndex:0]];
}
NSLog(@"oauth_token_secret : %@", params[@"oauth_token_secret"]);    
NSLog(@"oauth_token : %@", params[@"oauth_token"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that returns string between two characters. This is return you oath token. Change it according to your need.

```
-(NSString*)contentsInStrings:(NSString *)str
{
NSString *subString = nil;
NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:@"&oauth_token="];
NSRange range2 = [str rangeOfString:@"&"];
if ((range1.length == 1) && (range2.length == 1) && (range2.location > range1.location))
{
    NSRange range3;
    range3.location = range1.location+1;
    range3.length = (range2.location - range1.location)-1;
    subString = [str substringWithRange:range3];
}
return subString;
}
```